# git detached head in source causes 'git submodule update' failure with 'fatal: Needed a single revision'

Tags: git

Here is a test bash script to reconstruct this problem, `git --version` says "git version 1.9.1". Basically, I have a "source submodule" repo `/tmp/TestSubber`, which I use as submodule in a "source superproject" `/tmp/TestMain` repo - and the source I want to clone "locally" as `/tmp/TestLocMain`, and in the clone initialize the submodule:

```bash
set -x

rm -rfv /tmp/TestSubber /tmp/TestMain /tmp/TestLocMain
mkdir /tmp/TestSubber /tmp/TestMain
cd /tmp/TestSubber; git init;
git config user.name me; git config user.name me@example.com;
echo "aaaa" >> a.txt ; git add a.txt; git commit -m 'commit 01'
echo "aaaa" >> a.txt ; git add a.txt; git commit -m 'commit 02'
echo "aaaa" >> a.txt ; git add a.txt; git commit -m 'commit 03'
echo "aaaa" >> a.txt ; git add a.txt; git commit -m 'commit 04'
git checkout HEAD~2
git status # HEAD detached at f221985

cd /tmp/TestMain; git init;
git config user.name me; git config user.name me@example.com;
echo "bbbb" >> b.txt ; git add b.txt; git commit -m 'commit 01'
git submodule add -b master --depth 1 -- https://github.com/rtyley/small-test-repo TestSubber
git add -u; git commit -m 'added submodule'

cd /tmp
git clone file:///tmp/TestMain /tmp/TestLocMain
cd TestLocMain
sed -i"" 's!https://github.com/rtyley/small-test-repo!file:///tmp/TestSubber!g' .gitmodules
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init --remote --depth 1 --merge -- TestSubber
```

When you run this script, the last step with `git submodule update` will fail with:

```
...
+ git submodule update --init --remote --depth 1 --merge -- TestSubber
Submodule 'TestSubber' (file:///tmp/TestSubber) registered for path 'TestSubber'
Cloning into 'TestSubber'...
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
From file:///tmp/TestSubber
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current origin/master revision in submodule path 'TestSubber'
```

Seemingly the problem is the `git checkout HEAD~2` in the source submodule repo `/tmp/TestSubber`, which forces that repo in a detached HEAD state; if you comment the line `git checkout HEAD~2`, then the final steps succeeds with:

```
...
+ git submodule update --init --remote --depth 1 --merge -- TestSubber
Submodule 'TestSubber' (file:///tmp/TestSubber) registered for path 'TestSubber'
Cloning into 'TestSubber'...
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule path 'TestSubber': checked out 'ad110f4932339fe5efb940608139b08a28b8c518'
```

Now, my actual use case is that what corresponds to `TestSubber` is huge, and needs to remain in the detached HEAD state for the time being. Is there anything I can do to force submodule update in `TestLocMain` to complete successfully, without changing the state of `TestSubber`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like I got it - basically, one needs to reconstruct the `/tmp/TestLocMain/.git/modules/TestSubber` as a bare repo, then do a git pull with it as GIT_DIR, and `/tmp/TestLocMain/TestSubber` as GIT_WORK_TREE, then finally issue the `git submodule update...` command (which now does not need a `--merge` or anything). Note that I added a generation and adding of a 100MB file, to test whether the `git submodule update...` command will also perform a full checkout (apparently, it doesn't):

```bash
set -x

rm -rfv /tmp/TestSubber /tmp/TestMain /tmp/TestLocMain
mkdir /tmp/TestSubber /tmp/TestMain
cd /tmp/TestSubber; git init;
git config user.name me; git config user.name me@example.com;
echo "aaaa" >> a.txt ; git add a.txt; git commit -m 'commit 01'
echo "aaaa" >> a.txt ; git add a.txt; git commit -m 'commit 02'
echo "aaaa" >> a.txt ; git add a.txt; git commit -m 'commit 03'
echo "aaaa" >> a.txt ; git add a.txt; git commit -m 'commit 04'
dd if=/dev/urandom of=big.file bs=1M count=100
git add big.file; git commit -m 'commit 05 big.file'
git checkout HEAD~2
git status # HEAD detached at f221985

cd /tmp/TestMain; git init;
git config user.name me; git config user.name me@example.com;
echo "bbbb" >> b.txt ; git add b.txt; git commit -m 'commit 01'
git submodule add -b master --depth 1 -- https://github.com/rtyley/small-test-repo TestSubber
git add -u; git commit -m 'added submodule'

cd /tmp
git clone file:///tmp/TestMain /tmp/TestLocMain
cd TestLocMain
sed -i"" 's!https://github.com/rtyley/small-test-repo!file:///tmp/TestSubber!g' .gitmodules
git submodule sync
mkdir -p .git/modules/TestSubber
MODDIR="`cd .git/modules/TestSubber && pwd`"
GIT_DIR="$MODDIR" git init --bare
GIT_DIR="$MODDIR" git config core.bare false
GIT_DIR="$MODDIR" git remote add origin file:///tmp/TestSubber
cd /tmp/TestLocMain
echo 'gitdir: ../.git/modules/TestSubber' > TestSubber/.git
GIT_DIR="$MODDIR" GIT_WORK_TREE="/tmp/TestLocMain/TestSubber" git pull --depth=1 origin master

git submodule update --init --remote --depth 1 -- TestSubber
git submodule status
```